# How to retrieve FQDN of the current host on Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winsock

What's an easiest reliable way to retrieve the fully qualified domain name of the current host in Win32?

I've tried calling gethostname(), but it returns a NetBIOS name.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262425/translating-netbios-domain-into-a-fqdn-fully-qualified-domain-name

Comment: The answer there is not very useful - it references no code snippets with Win32 primitives at all.

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804700/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-get-the-fqdn-of-local-machine-in-c

Comment: That requires .NET framework.

Comment: No, really, I've googled before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`getnameinfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738532(VS.85).aspx), it comes with a sample that worked for me.